# Include js file MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to include .js file from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js in **MVC5** project to call the methods asynchronously. Presently I have achieved this including the same in cshtml file. This works fine. However not working if internet connection is down or very poor. The same situation may be arise in production. I think the best way is download the file & bundle same in project So that it won't depend on internet.

Kindly advise me  how to bundle the same & use in Project.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

Below is my BundleConfig.js

Comment: Just copy and paste the jQuery code into notepad, save as `jquery-1.12.0.js` and include that file in your Scripts directory under your solution and rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

To Make it fail safe if no internet connection. DO something like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")';
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);

    }
</script> 

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Great . it works .. I just added  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") in my view